# F# exists where function?

Tags: f#, where-clause, exists

I have a function processing a DataTable looking for any row that has a column with a certain value. It looks like this:

```
let exists = 
    let mutable e = false
    for row in dt.Rows do
        if row.["Status"] :?> bool = false
            then e <- true
    e
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in a single expression.  For example, Python has the "any" function which would do it something like this:

```
exists = any(row for row in dt.Rows if not row["Status"])
```

Can I write a similar one-liner in F# for my exists function?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Seq.exists` function, which takes a predicate and returns true if the predicate holds for at least one element of the sequence.

```
let xs = [1;2;3]
let contains2 = xs |> Seq.exists (fun x -> x = 2)
```

But in your specific case, it won't work right away, because `DataTable.Rows` is of type `DataRowCollection`, which only implements `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<T>`, and so it won't be considered a "sequence" in F# sense, which means that `Seq.*` functions won't work on it. To make them work, you have to first cast the sequence to the correct type with `Seq.cast`:

```
let exists = 
   dt.Rows |> 
   Seq.cast<DataRow> |> 
   Seq.exists (fun r -> not (r.["Status"] :?> bool) )
```

Comment: As an aside, F# is perfectly able to infer the collection type in sequence expressions: `seq{for r in dt.Rows -> r.["Status"]} |> Seq.forall unbox |> not`

Comment: perfect!  nice and succinct

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested):

`dt.Rows |> Seq.exists (fun row -> not (row.["Status"] :?> bool))`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.exists%5b%27t%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d

Comment: Alas: Error 52 The type 'DataRowCollection' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'

Comment: Alas.  I thought IEnumerable was sufficient to use with Seq.